# Sorting names in an array variable inside a structure alphabetically

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, structure

I'm making this student record program that my prof asked us to do. It keeps saying `cannot convert 'StudRec' to 'StudRec' in assignment` and sometimes it says `cannot convert char* to const char*`. `StudRec` is my struct variable and this is the function that should sort the recorded names alphabetically.

```
void sort_name(StudRec name[], StudRec temp[], int studcount)
{
    if (studcount > 0)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<studcount; i++)
        {
           for (int j=studcount; j<=i; j++)
            {
                if(strcmp(name[j].nm, name[j+1].nm) > 0)
                {
                        temp=name[j];
                        name[j]= name[j+1];
                        name[j+1]= temp;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "\t| |\t\t\t The records have been sorted alphabetically by name.\n";
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "\t| |\t\t\t There is no current record to sort by name.\n\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide at least the declaration of `StudRec`, the actual compiler error, and the caller code. anyway, even if that would compile, your inner loop would always be skipped because`j` is always greater than `i`.

Comment: First, `j` will always be more than `i`, since you're initializing it at `studcount`, which `i` will never reach. I'm assuming you want that to be `int j = studcount; j>i; j--`.

Second, show StudRec and which line the errors are happening on.

Comment: struct StudRec
        {
            string id;
            char nm[50];
            char sex, temp;
            float acts, quiz, hw, midT, fExam, proj, total=0, fgrd=0;
};

Oh, I'm sorry here is the declaration of StudRec and the lines of error is in the 

temp=name[j]

The studcount variable is the one that counts how many records is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, assuming that the `StudRec` has all necessary operations (assignment, default constructor, etc.), you don't need to pass an array of temp values:

```
void sort_name(StudRec name[], int studcount)
{
    StudRec temp;
    // ...
}
```

That should fix one issue: you are trying to assign an element to the whole array:

```
        temp=name[j];
```

Even better would be to define `temp` right where you use it:

```
        const StudRec temp = name[j];
```

Anyway, I guess you are trying to implement a BubbleSort, and your implementation is incorrect because of the indexing. Should be:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < studcount; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < studcount - i; ++j)
```

Comment: It fixes my problem man. It compiles. But the problem now is that I input 3 students and their names are "JJ Perez", "Abad Ry", and "Sassy Dy". But when the function sort_name is executed then I view all the records,  "'Abad Ry" did not come first in the record list. JJ is still in the first line

Comment: See my comment regarding the indexing.

Comment: Last question man, there is this problem with my setprecision. I have a function to get the final grade of students with setprecision when I cout it so that it rounds the grade off by 2. When the code runs and I calculate the final grade. It is correct, but when I view all the records,(I also have a different function to view all records) the raw scores are also displaying with setprecision in it(such as 150.00) . But when I view first all the records it does not have any .00.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code in the fGrade function:

```
    void fGrade(StudRec rec[], int studcount)
    {
    string id;

if (studcount > 0)
{
    cout << "\n\n\t| |\t\t         =====================================================\n";
    cout << "\t| |\t\t\t\t         STUDENT'S FINAL GRADE \n";
    cout << "\t| |\t\t         =====================================================\n\n";;
    check:  cout << "\n\t| |\t\t\t Enter student's ID Number: ";
            cin >> id;

            int index = search(rec, id, studcount);

            if (index != -1 && studcount > 0)
            {
                rec[index].fgrd = (((rec[index].quiz / 150) * 100) * 0.2) + (((rec[index].hw / 20) * 100) * 0.1) + (((rec[index].midT / 100) * 100) * 0.15)
        + (((rec[index].fExam / 100) * 100) * 0.15) + (((rec[index].acts / 150) * 100) * 0.25) + (((rec[index].proj / 100) * 100) * 0.15);

        cout << left << setw(10) << "\n ID No." << setw(30) << "NAME" << setw(15) << "FINAL GRADE" << setw(10) << "REMARKS";
        cout << "\n ------------------------------------------------------------\n";
        cout << " " << left << setw(8) << rec[index].id << setw(30) << rec[index].nm << setw(15) << fixed << setprecision(2) << rec[index].fgrd;

        if (rec[index].fgrd >= 75 && rec[index].fgrd <= 100)
        {
            cout << setw(10) << "Passed\n\n";
        }

        else if (rec[index].fgrd < 75)
        {
            cout << setw(10) << "Failed\n\n";
        }
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "\t| |\t\t\t This record does not exist. Check your ID and try again.";
        goto check;
    }
}

else
{
    cout << "\t| |\t\t\t There is no current record to calculate a final grade.\n\n";
    return;
}
    }
```

and this is the code for the view_rec function:

```
    void view_rec(StudRec rec[], int studcount)
    {
if (studcount > 0)
{
    cout << "\n\n\t| |\t\t         ===================================================\n";
    cout << "\t| |\t\t\t\t         VIEW STUDENT RECORD \n";
    cout << "\t| |\t\t         ===================================================\n\n";
    int i=0;
    cout << "\n\t| |\t\t         " << left << setw(10) << "ID" << setw(30) << "NAME" << setw(7) << "SEX" << setw(10) << "QUIZ";
    cout << setw(14)<< "ASSIGNMENT" << setw(11) << "MIDTERM" << setw(14) << "FINAL EXAM" << setw(12) << "ACTIVITY";
    cout << setw(11)<< "PROJECT" << setw(9) << "TOTAL\n";
    cout << "\t| |\t\t         " << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";

    while(i <= studcount)
    {
        if(rec[i].id != "")
        {

            cout << "\t| |\t\t         " << left << setw(10) << rec[i].id << setw(30) << rec[i].nm << setw(7) << rec[i].sex;
            cout << setw(10) << rec[i].quiz << setw(14) << rec[i].hw << setw(11) << rec[i].midT;
            cout << setw(14) << rec[i].fExam << setw(12) << rec[i].acts << setw(11) << rec[i].proj << setw(9) << rec[i].total;
            cout << endl << endl;
        }
        i+=1;
    }
}

else
{
    cout << "\t| |\t\t\t There is no current record to view.\n\n";
    return;
}
```

}